# Change default dialog buttons text color without changing colorAccent attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

In android, the default dialog buttons(Negative, neutral and positive) text color is same as colorAccent(in colors.xml) attribute but I want to set some different color without changing colorAccent attribute. I looked everywhere but I couldn't find any way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change default dialog button text color in android 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965662/how-can-i-change-default-dialog-button-text-color-in-android-5)

Comment: this is very different question from what you say it is duplicate @Amin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `alertDialogTheme` in the main AppTheme, and then define a different colorAccent in that theme, which is specific to AlertDialogs:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I checked it before post, check again. Do you use AlertDialog v7?

Comment: No, I am using `android.app.AlertDialog`. What should I use?

Comment: android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Comment: I changed to v7.AlertDialog and it worked, thanks @gurgen