# Android change color of AlertDialog elements

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-xml

I would like to change the colors of the AlertDialog elements using only xml.

The elements I want to change using xml are:

1. Background color of the AlertDialog
2. Url text color
3. Line color of textInput when focused
4. Color of the text on the two AlertDialog buttons

I would like the size of the AlertDialog to remain unchanged.

I tried using the styles: [How can I change default dialog button text color in android 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965662/how-can-i-change-default-dialog-button-text-color-in-android-5)

But they don't work and the size of the AlertDialog changes, it shrinks.

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

```java
public void AlertDialog() {
        View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.text_input, null);
        final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.input);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Url");
        builder.setView(viewInflated);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            String text = input.getText().toString();
            if (!text.equals("")) pinAppWidget(text);
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
        builder.show();
    }
```

text_input.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text" />

</FrameLayout>
```

values/themes.xml

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Test" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Base.Theme.Test" />
</resources>
```

values-night/themes.xml

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Test" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your dark theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_dark_primary</item> -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you limited this a only xml files, you can stared with you theme. You're gonna need create a new theme that inherits the desired characteristics, let's use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert` that will serve for you.  Then override the theme defaut properts of AlertDialog. You can make this it.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.Theme.Test" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.CustomThemeAlertDialog</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.CustomThemeAlertDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
    <!--Background color-->
    <item name="android:background">#0000ff</item>

    <!--tittle color-->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

    <!--text color of message-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>

    <!--text color of buttons-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFF00</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Test" parent="Base.Theme.Test" />
```

The default result of an simple AlertDialog is this it (without your custom View)[image]

And to finish add the properts `android:textColor="@color/color_text_url"` (for Url text color) and `android:backgroundTint="@color/color_line_input_url"` (for Line color of textInput when focused) in your `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/color_text_url"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/color_line_input_url" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And is that

Comment: The writing of the two buttons does not change, maybe it will be another property?

Is there any way to know what the default colors are?
For example I would like to keep the same colors as the background, but if I take it off it doesn't work well.

Comment: Your customThemeAlertDialog is inheriting `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkHsJ.png

Comment: Strange. Did you create for the two theme versions, Night and Day? Here it works normally, I tested it.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rryBE.png

Comment: Tried both, same thing.

The only thing that changes is that in the Day version there is `<style name="Theme.Test" parent="Base.Theme.Test" />`

Comment: Try to put all the items that are in the image in the answer I'll try if they work.

Comment: just the modification https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1jV5.png

Comment: Can you pass me your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sg7uk5DN

Comment: I haven't identified any reason for errors, I've posted the full version of the App I'm using, hope it helps https://github.com/kllysmman/stackoverflow

Comment: Tried the two issues first it was `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">` instead it had to be`<item name="alertDialogTheme">`.

Comment: I had to use the following libraries:
`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`