# AlertDialog MultipleChoice Doesn't Show Items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multiple-choice

I'm having a problem regarding of displaying the items int the `AlertDialog`.
I check the code and it's ok. Only the `items` doesn't show.

Here's my code:

```
//PREFERENCE CATEGORY - DIALOG
public void alertDialogPrefCat(){
    //TODO -
    String[] categories = new String[]{"Health","Universities","Scholars","Professionals",
                           "Business","Engineering","Architecture","Foundations",
                           "Charities", "Culture", "Technology","Blog", "Music",
                           "Sports","Insurance"};
    //GET CHECKED
       final boolean[] selectedCategory = new boolean[]{false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false,
                                           false
       };

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCategoryPicker = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final List<String> itemGet = Arrays.asList(categories);

    alertDialogCategoryPicker.setTitle("Interest: ")
                             .setMessage("Select category of org you want.")
                             .setCancelable(false)
                             .setMultiChoiceItems(categories, selectedCategory,
                             new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                selectedCategory[which] = isChecked;
                                String currentItem = itemGet.get(which);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                             })
                             .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                     }
                             });

    AlertDialog dialogCategory = alertDialogCategoryPicker.create();
    dialogCategory.show();

}
```

I get this Dialog with empty items.

[image: sample]

Comment: you can create your own custom dialog which is easy to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setMultiChoiceItems()` and `setMessage()` can not use together. 
Try to remove `.setMessage("Select category of org you want.")`

Refer links:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

[setMultiChoiceItems and setMessage not "working" in AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831975/setmultichoiceitems-and-setmessage-not-working-in-alertdialog)

Comment: Wow, your right. Thank you very muches! Is there a way I can inform users though? hhmm.. :/

Comment: Yes. You can inform to user from create custom layout for alertdialog.

Comment: Yes. Put that info in the Title too.